# How to add lua support into nginx

Tags: nginx, lua, debian, apt, openresty

Os: Linux, distribution: Debian (buster)

Currently, we using nginx:1.14.2, and to support Lua we are using libnginx-mod-http-lua:1.14.2 package.

We are working on upgrading Nginx to nginx:1.21.0 version and I'm unable to find the compatible libnginx-mod-http-lua package.

How to add Lua support into Nginx?
The only alternate way I'm able to find is using [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#installation) (it recommend to directly use openresty). Is there no other way to resolve this?

Comment: Why don't you want to use lua-nginx-module/openresty?